# datapatch fails with ISNONORACLECLOUD must be declared

Tags: oracle, patch

When trying to apply datapatch 31312468 to oracle 12.2.0.1 get the following:

Error at line 8833: 4675/23  PLS-00302: component 'ISNONORACLECLOUD' must be declared

Any ideas?

upd:
Datapatch Build label: RDBMS_12.2.0.1.0DBAPR2019RU_LINUX.X64_190227

Datapatch output: (for different patch, but it is exactly the same)

```
./datapatch -verbose
SQL Patching tool version 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 23 11:27:05 2020
Copyright (c) 2012, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Log file for this invocation: /local/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_541_2020_07_23_11_27_05/sqlpatch_invocation.log

Connecting to database...OK
Bootstrapping registry and package to current versions...done
Determining current state...done

Current state of SQL patches:
Patch 26635944 ():
  Not installed in the binary or the SQL registry
Patch 29249637 (OJVM RELEASE UPDATE: 12.2.0.1.190416 (29249637)):
  Installed in the binary registry only
Bundle series DBRU:
  ID 190416 in the binary registry and not installed in the SQL registry

Adding patches to installation queue and performing prereq checks...
Installation queue:
  Nothing to roll back
  The following patches will be applied:
    29249637 (OJVM RELEASE UPDATE: 12.2.0.1.190416 (29249637))
    29314339 (DATABASE APR 2019 RELEASE UPDATE 12.2.0.1.190416)

Installing patches...
Patch installation complete.  Total patches installed: 2

Validating logfiles...
Patch 29249637 apply: SUCCESS
  logfile: /local/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/29249637/22802302/29249637_apply_ORCL_2020Jul23_11_27_18.log (no errors)
Patch 29314339 apply: WITH ERRORS
  logfile: /local/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/29314339/22821655/29314339_apply_ORCL_2020Jul23_11_27_19.log (errors)
    Error at line 3715: Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 32330: Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 32337: 4675/4   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    Error at line 32338: 4675/23  PLS-00302: component 'ISNONORACLECLOUD' must be declared
    Error at line 32360: 4675/4   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    Error at line 32361: 4675/23  PLS-00302: component 'ISNONORACLECLOUD' must be declared
    Error at line 33014: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 33021: 0/0      PLS-00905: object GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_POOLADMIN is invalid
    Error at line 33038: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 33045: 0/0      PLS-00905: object GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_POOLADMIN is invalid
    Error at line 33052: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 33059: 0/0      PLS-00905: object GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_POOLADMIN is invalid

Please refer to MOS Note 1609718.1 and/or the invocation log
/local/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_541_2020_07_23_11_27_05/sqlpatch_invocation.log
for information on how to resolve the above errors.

SQL Patching tool complete on Thu Jul 23 11:27:47 2020
```

Comment: can you provide more details ? which Opatch version are you using ? what is the output of datapatch --verbose ? did you check for conflicts before running opatch ?

Comment: This is the kind of thing best addressed by opening an SR with Oracle Support.

Comment: Any news on that problem? I faced the same today when trying to do datapatch on a container database. Non-container worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around loading the following objects prior to running datapatch:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/dbmsgwmco.sql 
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/dbmsgwmut.sql 
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/dbmspool.sql
```